# SQL - Find the most recent date the status change (downgrade) and the # of total instances

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions, calculation

I have two tables: A and B. A holds the today's data and B holds the snapshot of each day's data (basically a history table with each day's data appended).

Table A

```
Date       ID  Status
2/6/2020   N1  1
2/6/2020   N2  2
```

Table B

```
Date       ID  Status
2/2/2020   N1  1
2/3/2020   N1  2
2/4/2020   N1  2
2/5/2020   N1  2
2/6/2020   N1  1
2/2/2020   N2  3
2/3/2020   N2  2
2/4/2020   N2  3
2/5/2020   N2  2
2/6/2020   N2  2
```

The status can change upward (e.g. 1 -> 2) or downward (e.g. 3 -> 1). I only care downward change. Not every record (ID) will have downward change. Assuming the date format is the default one, and there are much more dates in the table B and much more IDs

What I'd like to get are:

1. When was the status last changed downward to the current status (based on table A's status) for each ID. So for N1 it was 2/6/2020, and for N2 it was 2/5/2020
2. How many times did downward change happen for each ID. So N1 had 1 time and N2 had 2 times.
3. How many IDs are there whose current status is lower than the previous status. In this example, there are 2 (N1 and N2)

Thank you!!

Q1 result

```
Date      ID  Status
2/6/2020  N1  1
2/5/2020  N2  2
```

Q2 result

```
ID  Times
N1  1
N2  2
```

Q3 result

```
Total
2
```

Comment: Please show us your expected result as tabular text

Comment: @GMB added. Thanks!